# React Js TypeError: Cannot read property 'LoginAuth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to call a function from after doing a map of an array to check the values for any that match my variables but i want to do it in a separate function so i try and call the function and i get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'LoginAuth' of undefined

my code is this

```
LoginAuth = (Res) => {
    if (this.username === this.state.Username) {
        console.log("get to login auth and true");
    } else {
        console.log("Gets to login auth and false");
    }
}
CheckLoginAuth() {
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    console.log("Username=" + this.state.Username);
    console.log("Password=" + this.state.Password);
    this.props.AuthRes.map(function (Res) {
        console.log("ID=" + Res.id);
        console.log("Username=" + Res.username);
        console.log("Password=" + Res.password);
        this.LoginAuth(Res);//react is actually throwing the error here.
    })
}
```

how come this is erroring it gets called when i click a button on a form that bit works its just this new function.

Comment: binding issue, use arrow function: `this.props.AuthRes.map( (Res) => {`

Comment: Mayank is right, it's a scope issue, using a fat arrow function will fix your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the `map` function does not go to the `this` you want and is in fact **undefined** in itself.

also, as the people said in the comment, why not use a fat arrow?
No need to use the `function` call but if you want to keep it like that, here it goes.

**Try this:**

notice:

```
var self = this;
```

and calling `self.login...`

```
LoginAuth = (Res) => {
    if (this.username === this.state.Username) {
        console.log("get to login auth and true");
    } else {
        console.log("Gets to login auth and false");
    }
}
CheckLoginAuth() {
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    console.log("Username=" + this.state.Username);
    console.log("Password=" + this.state.Password);
var self = this;
    this.props.AuthRes.map(function (Res) {
        console.log("ID=" + Res.id);
        console.log("Username=" + Res.username);
        console.log("Password=" + Res.password);
        self.LoginAuth(Res);//react is actually throwing the error here.
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but why does setting a variable to this and replacing it on this.LoginAuth(Res); fix it, just so i understand more?

Comment: because `this` is referring to your `React` component but **NOT** in a `foreach`. `map` is a `foreach` kind of function, therefor the `this` is unknown. Think of a `foreach` as a separate "component"

Comment: ah ok makes sense